# How to scrapy a lazy loading form?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using Scrapy 1.2 to crawl an online database(http://bddatabase.net/jp/weapon/).

Here's a glance of my code:

```
class BdItemSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bdspider"

    start_urls = [
        "http://bddatabase.net/jp/weapon/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = BdItem()
        items = response.xpath("//table[@id='WeaponTable']/tbody//tr/td/text()")
        print(items.extract())
```

And here's the log:

```
2016-11-22 18:23:14 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-11-22 18:23:14 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-11-22 18:23:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-11-22 18:23:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://bddatabase.net/jp/weapon/> (referer: None)
['Loading data from server']
2016-11-22 18:23:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://bddatabase.net/jp/weapon/>
{}
2016-11-22 18:23:16 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

It returned a **Loading data from server** message.
I find the page loads the form 1~1.5sec after I refresh it. So I am wondering how can I get the items in this form correctly since it seems to provide a dynamic form rather than a static one.

Comment: search for something called "javascript rendering". If you still can't figure out how to check that, use something like [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two ways to solve this problem.

The first one, as commented by eLRuLL, is to actually do the JavaScript rendering. However, Selenium might be more complex than needed. You can try and use a headless browser like PhantomJS or Splash. These headless browsers will render the JavaScript for you. This method is relatively easy to implement, but does have its impact on the performance of the scraper.

The second option is actually scraping the HTTP location of the XHR request. Within Firefox you can use the Firebug extension to filter all XHR requests and find the right request. Generally this option gives me an improved performance, though it can be more complex to implement.